# NUnit TestEngine throws "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" when trying to explore assembly

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm working on a tool that needs to extract the NUnit tests names that are contained in an assembly.
As I need the exact name of the tests when they are run, and NUnit's way of naming the tests is not straightforward, I use the NUnit TestEngine to explore the assembly.

Something like that :

```
    Assembly testAssembly; //loaded somewhere else

    using var testEngine = new TestEngine();
    testEngine.WorkDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(testAssembly.Location);
    var       package    = new TestPackage(testAssembly.Location);
    using var runner     = testEngine.GetRunner(package);
    var       testsFound = runner.Explore(new TestFilter(string.Empty));
```

I build the whole tool with one of our projects as test subject, and it works well.
But when I try it on other similar projects (.Net 6, NUnit test projects for a web API), I have the following error :

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The tests run properly inside the Visual Studio, with VS test runner or Resharper.
The current directory is set to the `bin` folder.

Looking at the project, it seems that this is a implicit dependency of `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Hosting` (referenced by AppInsight)

[image: dependencies]

But :

- I don't see any version 6.0.0.
- I have another similar project that loads properly and have the exact same dependencies
- I can't find any Nuget package that has this version (highest is 2.2.0), so I can't force the reference.
- The Assembly loads properly (with `Assembly.LoadFrom()`), it fails in NUnit, [when it tries to call `LoadTests`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/main/src/NUnitEngine/nunit.engine.core/Drivers/NUnitNetStandardDriver.cs#L85)

I can't find where this reference is needed and why one solution is working and others are not, while they are very similar !

I'm out of ideas to make it work, so I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: You're running into issue #1274, which was identified in the 3.16 release.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply telling NUnit to produce the list of tests for you?

The `--explore` option followed by a file name creates XML output but without a following name it produces a readable list of names on the console. You can redirect the output to a file if that's what you want.

```
nunit3-console yourtests.dll --explore
```

UPDATE

Make sure you use the standard .NET Framework build of NUnit3-console with the above option, not the .NET 6.0 build. The standard runner creates whatever process is needed to properly explore the test assembly.

Comment: Well that creates a new world of errors :) `System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler'`. I'll see what I can do, but I was hoping to do everything by code, running an external command line and get the result generates a bunch of new problems to solve (first : knowing where it is !) :)

Comment: The exception suggests that you are trying to get NUnit to load a .NET Core test into a .NET framework process. I probably should have asked some questions before answering... like... where did you get the build of the engine you are using and how what runtimes you are targeting. See update in my answer as well.

Comment: I'm targetting .NET 6 libs, and I used the console that is in the nuget package. Indeed, if I download the console from NUnit website, it works. This is not an ideal solution, for a good workaround, thanks.
I still don't understand why it doesn't want to load the assembly.

Comment: You don't say __which__ package you downloaded from nuget. There is more than one.

Comment: My project references these NUnit packages : NUnit (3.13.3), NUnit.Engine (3.16.0), NUnit.Engine.Api (3.16.0), my app being a .NET 6 app, I guess it downloaded the NETStandard 2.0 version.

Comment: The issue is not with NUnit runner, it's with the assembly loading, I can reproduce it without NUnit. It seems that the solution generates reference assemblies in a subfolder "refs" and the assembly loader doesn't seem to see them. So I guess I asked the wrong question. Sorry !